# Add blank line before end of file with export

Tags: export, mac-os-x

I have a `list` of points (e.g. `{1.2,0.4}`) which I export to a file using

```
Export[fileName, list];
```

I want to add a line before the end of file. For instance instead of ending the file with

```
1.236677 4.64567567
1.236677 4.64567567
1.236676 4.64567567
```

ending like

```
1.236677 4.64567567
1.236677 4.64567567
1.236676 4.64567567
# a blank line here
```

I tried appending `{}`, `{,}`, `""` to the list, but none of them added a blank line.

I need this because xmgrace is not parsing the last line of the exported mathematica file: it expects a blank line before the End of File.

---

EDIT: As pointed out in the comments by Kuba and Pinguin Dirk, appending `""` works on Windows XP (and probably others.) I'm using OS X.

Comment: maybe something like: `Export["foo.txt", Append[list, ""]]`?

Comment: I already tried that but it doesn't work. If I use " ", it prints a new line with a white space in it.

Comment: @J.C.Leitão What OS are you working on? Pinguin Dirk's solution works on WinXP.

Comment: @Kuba very good!! It's true, I'm working on OS X. I will add that to the question.

Comment: Pinguin Dirk's solution works for me on OS X, Mathematica version 9. I thought to append a "\n", but that added two blank lines. Then I found that "" added just one.

Comment: If all else fails: `file=OpenAppend["file"]; Write["\n"]; Close[file]`

Comment: @cormullion, yep, OS X here too, and I too tried "\n". What file type are you exporting to?

Comment: Bah, the line is there. The program I was using to see the file was not showing it, but xmgrace was importing the file correctly. Sorry for the mess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here, on my OSX the following works

```
Export["tmp/foo.txt", Append[Range[10], "\n"]]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
Export[fileName, Append[list, ""], "Table"]
```

This should be OS-independent although I cannot check this under OS X.

Comment: Doesn't work with OSX. At least on my 9.0.1 with OSX 10.8.4